# "Turn Windows features on or off" opens "Server Manager"

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am trying to install IIS on my windows 10 Hyper V machine.

When i clicks on "Turn Windows features on or off" rather then default window it opens "Server Manager" and its add role wizard.

[image]

Comment: So, is it *really* Windows 10? Do you need Server Manager? You could try uninstalling it.

Comment: Where's the problem? Just use the server manager to do whatever you want to do?

Comment: @DanielB you point me in the right direction that it's not windows 10. Actually it's windows 2016 server. To install IIS I found this helpful link https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-install-iis-in-windows-server-2016/

Comment: Run appwiz.cpl from cmd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To install IIS on Windows 2016, follow the wizard.

1. Open Server Manager
2. Add roles and features
3. Next
4. Check Role based or feature based installation
5. Next
6. Choose your server from the pool
7. Next
8. Scroll down and choose Web Server and install the components you want

On the next screen you may need to also install the additional .NET framework(s)